# How do I connect to the iTunes COM on windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

In a c# project I just add the COMReference to the csproj and then import the iTunesLib wherever I need it. With the windows script host I think I can do something like:

```
var iTunesApp = WScript.CreateObject("iTunes.Application");
```

How can I use/import those references with nodejs or electron?

Comment: The only solution I found there was the 'win32ole' lib but that only works in  version ">= 0.8.18 && < 0.9.0" of node, what a shame.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of options:

- Write a native Node module in C++ that interfaces with the iTunes lib via COM.
- Write a C# assembly that interfaces with the iTunes lib, then use it in Electron via [Edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge).